# Singularity image

Tags: image, containers, singularity-container

I wrote the following definition file:

```
Bootstrap: library
From: ubuntu:18.04

%post
apt-get update
apt-get install -y r-base r-base-dev libpng-dev libtiff-dev libjpeg-dev
R --slave -e 'install.packages("devtools", repos="https://cloud.r-project.org/")'
R --slave -e 'install.packages("Rcpp")'
R --slave -e 'install.packages("methods")'
R --slave -e 'library("devtools")'
R --slave -e 'devtools::install_github("benjjneb/dada2", ref="v1.16")'

%test
R --slave -e 'packageVersion("dada2")' 

%labels
Author Francesca
Version 1.0

%help
This singularity container contains R and dada2, a bioinformatic tool used for 
analysing 16s rRNA data.
```

However when I try to build the image (`sudo singularity build dada2.sif def_file.def`) I receive this error:
`ERROR: 'Bootstrap' type not supported: library`
How can I solve this issue? Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

You can use biocontainers to do that.

In your def file:

```
Bootstrap : docker
From: quay.io/biocontainers/bioconductor-dada2:1.22.0--r41h619a076_1

%post
```